# use vertcat for concatenate columns of matrix to make 1D column

Tags: matlab, matrix, svd

let us consider following bit of code:

```
[m,n]=size(X);

if m == (n+1)
     Z = vertcat(U(:,1:2:d), V(:,1:2:d));
else
     Z = vertcat(U(:,[1:2:d]));
end

C=Z(:);
```

What I want it to do is concatenate the singular vectors into one column vector. For example, I want to concatenate the first d left and right singular vectors, but the problem is that it creates a multidimensional column, that's why I  wrote  C=Z(:). But, can I  use vertcat to just create a 1D column vector? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have just flipped your row and column indexing. U(:,1:2:d) will return a row vector, which you are then vertcating with another row vector. Try this instead:

```
[m,n]=size(X);

if m == (n+1)
     Z = vertcat(U(1:2:d,:), V(1:2:d,:));
else
     Z = vertcat(U([1:2:d]), :));
end

C=Z(:);
```

I hope that helps.